# Adding node to a linked list seems to use a reference. How do I avoid this?

Tags: c#, reference

**Edit:**

This is a better example of the problem i'm trying to solve.

```
var aNode = new Node<string>("please don't change");
var copiedNode = aNode;
copiedNode.value = "Hah! Changed.";
Console.WriteLine(aNode.value);
```

I'm new to c# and trying to learn some basics. I'm trying to implement a linked list, but it seems that when I add a node it gets passed by reference.

The first time I print I get exactly what I expect. After changing one of the nodes and printing out the list again, the node's values has been changed in the linked list. How do I avoid this?

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public T value;
    private Node<T> next;

    public Node(T val)
    {
        value = val;
        next = null;
    }

    public void SetNext(Node<T> node)
    {
        var currNode = this;
        while (currNode.next != null)
        {
            currNode = currNode.next;
        }
        currNode.next = node;
    }

    public void PrintAllNodes()
    {
        var currentNode = this;
        while (currentNode != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(currentNode.value);
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }

    }
}

public class LinkedList
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var head = new Node<string>("head Node");
        head.SetNext(new Node<string>("second node"));

        var toChange = new Node<string>("third node");
        head.SetNext(toChange);
        head.SetNext(new Node<string>("last node"));
        head.PrintAllNodes();

        Console.WriteLine("----");
        toChange.value = "changed!";
        //prints "changed!" now
        head.PrintAllNodes();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you not expect the Node print out to change?

Answer (score 1):

A `Node` *is itself a reference*.  You're not *passing* anything by reference, per say.  It's an important distinction.

As for solutions, generally speaking a `Node` in a `LinkedList` *should be immutable*.  Allow the contents of a `Node` to be specified in its constructor and then never let it be mutated, only read from.

Comment: Updated OP with better example.

Comment: @user3490130 I stand by my answer, even for that example.  Your node almost certainly ought to be immutable, and the reason you're seeing that behavior is because a `Node` variable is inherently a reference.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to make the Value of the Node immutable, so you cannot change it, you could make the `Value` into a `Property` and give it a `private` setter.

E.g.

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public T Value{ get; private set; }

    ...........
}
```

Or if you want it to for whatever reason, give it an empty Setter

```
public class Node<T>
{
        private T _value;
        public T Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set {  }
        }
 }
```

Although I would highly recommend making the setter private like in the first example

Comment: Code only answers are not as helpful as those that include explanations

Comment: You absolutely should *not* have a setter that doesn't do anything.  If the value shouldn't be set, simply don't expose a setter.